# Showing the incorrect textbox title

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code below is made to detect the name of the input method user focus in , the problem is it alerts the same name for all textboxes.

```
 var huntedTextBox;
    //focus in any textfield to get its name into the vairable.
    $("input").focus(function() {

        huntedTextBox  = $("input").attr('name');
        alert(huntedTextBox);

    });
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/baderalrayyes/duu938dy/) for the code.

Thanks.

Comment: try maybe  $(this).attr('name');

Comment: Because you are not in current context

Comment: You are checking the first input field and adds the first input name value to huntedTextBox. It should be on the input that you are on focus huntedTextBox  = $(this).attr('name');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just doing a search for `$('input')` will return all `<input>`s in the document. Then, doing `.attr()` will get the attribute for the first.

To get the attribute of the `<input>` that was clicked, use `$(this).attr('name');`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `this` for selecting that particular textbox that's focused on...
Here's a snippet:

```js
var huntedTextBox;
//focus in any textfield to get its name into the vairable.
$("input").focus(function() {

    huntedTextBox  = $(this).attr('name');
    alert(huntedTextBox);
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="textBox" />
<input type="text" name="Bader" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`huntedTextBox  = $(this).attr('name');`